# Setting target JVM in SBT

Tags: scala, sbt

How can I set target JVM version in SBT?
In Maven (with maven-scala-plugin) it can be done as follows:

```
<plugin>
...
    <configuration>
      <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
      <args>
         <arg>-target:jvm-1.5</arg>
      </args>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can specify compiler options in the project definition:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
```

Comment: In recent version of SBT, use this: `javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.5", "-target", "1.5")`

Comment: Also `scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.5"` (in `build.sbt`)

Answer (score 4):

you have to add(in your build.sbt file):

```
scalacOptions += "-target:jvm-1.8"
```

otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

As of versions in 2023, the option is now [`-release`](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/compiler-options/index.html#targeting-a-version-of-the-jvm) instead of `-target`

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by others in comments, the current sbt version (1.0, 0.13.15) uses the following notation for setting source and target JVMs.

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8")
```